# use OpenCV decomposeHomographyMat from Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, opencv

I'm trying to use openCV's `decomposeHomographyMat` function. I'm more of a Swift guy but for that I've to use Objective C mysterious language. The signature of the function is

```
cv::decomposeHomographyMat(
  <#InputArray H#>, 
  <#InputArray K#>, 
  <#OutputArrayOfArrays rotations#>,
  <#OutputArrayOfArrays translations#>, 
  <#OutputArrayOfArrays normals#>
)
```

I've an input K and H that are both `NSArray<NSNumber*> *_Nonnull` with 9 elements each.

How can I create the expected `InputArray` and `OutputArrayOfArrays`, and how do I convert `OutputArrayOfArrays` back to a type Objective C can pass to swift?

=== Edit ===

trying Quang answer crashed when calling `cv::decomposeHomographyMat` with:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()) in getMat_,
file .../opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1287
```

The code is:

```
+ (nullable NSArray<NSNumber*> *) decomposeHomography:(NSArray<NSNumber*> *_Nonnull) homography intrisics:(NSArray<NSNumber*> *_Nonnull) intrisics
{
  cv::Mat rotations, translations, normals;
  vector<vector<float> > H(3,vector<float>(3));
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j<3; ++j){
      H[i][j] = [homography[i*3 + j] floatValue];
    }
  }
  vector<vector<float> > K(3,vector<float>(3));
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j<3; ++j){
      K[i][j] = [intrisics[i*3 + j] floatValue];
    }
  }

  cv::decomposeHomographyMat(
                 H,
                 K,
                 rotations,
                 translations,
                 normals
  );
  NSLog(@"ok");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `NSArray` to `std::vector<vector<float> >` and feed it to `cv::decomposeHomographyMat`. For example

```
- (std::vector<std::vector<float> >) getVectorFrom: (NSArray *) arr{

    std::vector<std::vector<float> > ret(3,vector<float>(3));

    for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j<3; ++j){
            ret[i][j] = [arr[i*3 + j] floatValue];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

- (void) someFunction: (NSArray *)H with: (NSArray *)K{

     cv::Mat rotations, translations, normals;

     cv::decomposeHomographyMat([self.getVectorFrom H], 
                                [self.getVectorFrom K],
                                rotations,
                                translations,
                                normals);
}
```

Comment: using `std::vector<Mat>` for rotations, translations, normals; and Mat for H, K works. Thanks for putting me on the right direction